# Catalog price rules disappear after 24 hours in Magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, catalog-price-rules

We used two suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280095/ to solve this problem.

1. We applied the "line 121" fix to app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php
2. We also installed AOE scheduler and used the settings suggested by Lakshin Karunaratne at the end of the post.

Neither of these are working. After manually running all rules, all discount prices are reverted back to full price after 24 hours.

AOE is running successfully. However, catalogrule_apply_all is the only rule not running successfully. I see this has been quite an ongoing issue. Anyone have a fix?

Comment: I have no idea how or why this started working. After a couple days, sale prices stopped reverting and the rules remain applied.